# Copying a large file in parts from a NAS to a backup location?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, nas, file-transfer, copy

i have a backup of a 500GB veracrypt container on my NAS (mounted via SMB).
this NAS is dying right now, and i want to move all files to another storage. but i'm having a problem with this large file, since the copying keeps failing after a time.
I had the same problem with other files, but **after restarting it always seems to work fine for a little while**.

Of course, moving 500Gb takes more than a little while.

Now i'm looking for a way to copy a large file in chunks, initiated by the client, without having to edit the target file in any way.

Like "copy Bytes 0 - 100000", then "copy Bytes 100001 to 200000" and so on.
i imagine it should be very easy to do, and i was surprised when my google search returned zero relevant results.

is there a windows way to do this? if not, is there a linux way to do this? if not... is there ANY way to do this?

i'll be thankful for any help :)

Comment: Related question on [unix.se]: [Can rsync resume after being interrupted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48298/53467)

Comment: @gronostaj that's not quite the same. i want to minimize the uptime of the device and copy specified chunks of a big file one by one. like copy just the middle part of the file